# Changing Plot Font with Cairo in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, fonts, cairo

I have found R's default plots to be poorly aliased. As a solution, I set Cairo as the graphics device, and now the plots look much better.

[image]

Unfortunately, using Cairo has created another issue, which is that for some reason, I am not able to apply the font that I was using when the graph was displayed in the plot window (in the left-hand diagram above, Cambria is used, but the right-hand diagram fails to apply this font).

Here is my code:

```
library(readxl)
library(scales)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library('Cairo')

windowsFonts(Cam = windowsFont("Cambria"))

dataset <- read_excel('CW Data.xlsx')
colnames(dataset)[4] <- "Broadband Subs (%)"

options(scipen = 1000)

# Scatter plot FDI~GDP with regression line
CairoWin()
ggplot(dataset, aes(x=`2019 GDP ($bn)`, y=`2019 FDI ($m)`)) + 
  geom_point(size=3, shape=1) +
  geom_smooth(method='lm',formula=y~x, se=FALSE, color='black') +
  scale_x_continuous(label = comma) + scale_y_continuous(label=comma) +
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill="peachpuff"), 
        plot.background = element_rect(fill="peachpuff")) +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "gray72"), 
        panel.grid.minor = element_line(colour = "gray72")) + 
  theme(text = element_text(family = "Cam")) 

ggsave("FDI~GDP.png", device="png", type = "cairo")
```

And here is a OneDrive link for the Excel data that I am using

https://1drv.ms/x/s!AvGKDeEV3LOs4gNr714Ie0KbOjhO?e=bkdPvk

Comment: Ryan, instead of linking to one drive data, which is unstable and might require signing in, and might not work anymore in the future, would you care creating an example like suggested by teunbrand in his "answer"?

Comment: This is what I get from the OneDrive link: `This item might not exist or is no longer available
This item might have been deleted, expired, or you might not have permission to view it. `

Comment: Added the [windows] tag since I'm unable to reproduce on a Linux machine after swapping `x11Fonts` for the `windowsFonts` calls and using the MCVE in the non-answer below. I'm assuming that Cambria is supposed to produce a font that looks like the typewriter output of old (thin, serif, monospaced).

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you have a look at the packages `ragg` and `systemfonts`. They make working with fonts extremly easy and the results are better than the output of the base options.

First, I suggest you query all available fonts using `View(systemfonts::system_fonts())`. You can select every font present here and use it for plotting or saving a plot.

I recreated your plot using a built in dataset as the onedrive link you shared was broken. I used the Cambria font like this.

```r
plot <- ggplot(dataset, aes(x = mpg, y = hp)) +
  geom_point(size = 3, shape = 1) +
  geom_smooth(
    method = 'lm',
    formula = y ~ x,
    se = FALSE,
    color = 'black'
  ) +
  scale_x_continuous(label = comma) +
  scale_y_continuous(label = comma) +
  labs(x = "2019 GDP ($bn)", y = "2019 FDI ($m)") +
  theme(
    panel.background = element_rect(fill = "peachpuff"),
    plot.background = element_rect(fill = "peachpuff")
  ) +
  theme(
    panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "gray72"),
    panel.grid.minor = element_line(colour = "gray72")
  ) +
  theme(text = element_text(family = "Cambria")) # relevant line
```

I prefer saving the plot in an object and passing it explicitly to the save function.

```r
ggsave(
  "FDI~GDP.png", 
  plot = plot, 
  device = ragg::agg_png, # this is the relevant part
  width = 1920, 
  height = 1080,
  units = "px"
)
```

Here is the result:

[image: plot]

I would say it worked flawlessly. You can also use `ragg` as your graphics device in RStudio to make this more consistent. Have a look [here](https://github.com/r-lib/ragg#use-ragg-in-rstudio).

If you want to output the plot to a PDF, you can use `showtext` to register system fonts with all newly opening graphics devices. So what you need to do is:

```r
library(showtext)
showtext_auto()
ggsave(
  "FDI~GDP.pdf", 
  plot = plot,
  width = 1920, 
  height = 1080,
  units = "px"
)
```

Comment: The {ragg} package is great for producing raster graphics (+1), however that solution wouldn't work for vector graphics such as PDF or SVG.

Comment: That's true. SVG works with `svglite` but I didn't get PDF to work.

Comment: @teunbrand I think as long as your fonts are in afm format and registered via `pdfFonts` they should render correctly. Converting your TrueType fonts to afm and registering them is what the {extrafont} package does, and this certainly seemed to resolve the problem for me. I didn't want to post that as an answer though, as I presumed you would already have tried this?

Comment: Thanks for the tip, Alan! No I haven't tried this as I tried to steer clear of the {extrafont} package due to past frustrations. The afm format is entirely foreign to me, so I didn't know about this. Feel free to post an answer though!

Comment: There is a third new package for this called `showtext`. I updated my answer to show how it works.